# How to view a string or update a column on a database table depending on the values of other columns?

Tags: sql, database, null, sybase, switch-statement

I have a database table like that :-

Table1

```
Column1 : Varchar(50)
Column2 : Varchar(50)
Column3 : Boolean
Column4 : Varchar(50)
Column5 : Varchar(50)
```

I would like to create a dummy column -or add a new column to the table- when running a SQL statement so that the value is that column will hold a string indicating the satus of the row item depeing on more than one of these columns. I mean wether these columns have Null values or not.

A logical way to represent that:-

Select switch DummyColumn

```
"status1" Case column1 IS NOT NULL
"status2" Case column2 IS NOT NULL
"status3" Case column3 IS NOT NULL
"status4" Case column1 IS NOT NULL AND column2 IS NOT NULL
"status5" Case column2 IS NOT NULL AND column3 IS NULL
"status6" Case column2 IS NOT NULL OR column3 IS NOT NULL
```

From Table1;

In Business Logic, I can say I want to make display a string indicating the status of an Item in the database depeding on many other status columns which may be boolen or string and this status can have many values according to the values stored in these table columns.

My database engine is Sybase.

How I can build my SQL query to do that ? what may be this matter called ? How I can find or search for that ? I do not know in what topic I may find this ? I search about Merging, Concatening, Replacing, NVL,  and Union but i do not find what I seek for..

Thanks in Advance and I hope that I express my question well and that it is a duplicate and I hope to find a good answer for it as soon as possible ..

Comment: @user493325, do you realise that Status6 will never be returned because it will be overridden by Status1 or Status2, even where Status4 and Status5 are not applicable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's more than one way to skin a cat, this is one of them.

```
SELECT  t.Column1
        , t.Column2
        , t.Column3
        , t.Column4        
        , t.Column5
        , t.Column6
        , COALESCE(Status1, Status2, Status3, Status4, Status5, Status6) AS DummyColumn
FROM    (
          SELECT  *
                  , CASE WHEN Column1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status1' ELSE NULL END AS Status1
                  , CASE WHEN Column2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status2' ELSE NULL END AS Status2
                  , CASE WHEN Column3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status3' ELSE NULL END AS Status3
                  , CASE WHEN Column1 IS NOT NULL AND Column2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status4' ELSE NULL END AS Status4
                  , CASE WHEN Column2 IS NOT NULL AND Column3 IS NULL THEN 'status5' ELSE NULL END AS Status5
                  , CASE WHEN Column2 IS NOT NULL OR Column3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status6' ELSE NULL END AS Status6
          FROM    Table1
        ) t
```

Note that this works using SQL Server but as there are no arcane constructions involved, it should be relatively easy to convert this to SyBase.

Comment: you should probably re-order your COALESCE clause - at present, statuses 4 to 6 will never be selected because they will be overridden by statuses 1 to 3.

Comment: You are right, I hadn't noticed that. That is something only OP can resolve: either status1 should be returned or status4. Shuffling the COALESCE statement is indeed a solution.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer which gives me a hint to find a solution near that using Nested (Case When .. Then ..) Statements in Sybase T-SQL as I did not use COALESCE & Table Aliases but I have got the required results. Many Thanks for others (esp. Mark Bannister) too who commented on the Question and the Answer and makes it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Using a single CASE clause:

```
SELECT  Column1,
        Column2,
        Column3,
        Column4,       
        Column5,
        Column6,
        CASE WHEN Column1 IS NOT NULL AND Column2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status4'
             WHEN Column2 IS NOT NULL AND Column3 IS NULL THEN 'status5'
             WHEN Column1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status1'
             WHEN Column2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status2'
             WHEN Column3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status3'
             WHEN Column2 IS NOT NULL OR Column3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'status6'
        END  AS Dummy_Column
FROM    Table1
```

NB. Status6 will never be returned because it will be overridden by Status1 or Status2, even where Status4 and Status5 are not applicable.

Comment: If you need to select based on the status, the easiest thing is to wrap a query like Bannister's in an outer query so you can just operate on "Dummy_column" and not need to repeat the whole case statement. Also, DON'T add a column to the database for this. It's derivable, so derive it on the fly every time you need it. Then you don't have to worry about it getting out of sync with the underlying data.

Comment: @Jay - or you could set up a database view based on the query above, and then use the view as required.

Comment: @Bannister: True, depending whether you just need to do this for one query, in which case I wouldn't make a view as it would just break the code into two places; or you plan to use it in many places, in which case a view would mean not repeating yourself.